# bundle fails for installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

After I cloned a repo from `bitbucket`, on `bundle install` I am getting below error.

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.2'` succeeds before bundling.

when I tried to install `gem install pg -v '0.18.2'`, I get this.

> ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Please help in successful bundle instllation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have PostgreSQL libraries and build essentials installed to compile the native extension of PG.

For PostgreSQL libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

For Build essentials

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Assuming you are on an ubuntu machine

Comment: often the pg gem is only required in the group: :production. If this is the case and you just want to test your application in development mode, you can run, $ bundle install --without production. This will skip installing production gems/dependencies. Just make sure you have another database setup in your database.yml file (ie. sqlite). To bundle with production afterwards, edit the .bundle file created.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've been working with RoR for awhile now so you have a development environment configured to your liking, but I highly recommend ThoughtBot's (creator of FactoryGirl and PaperClip) extremely easy (it couldn't be more simple) development setup.

It's a script for OS X that configures Postgres, Foreman, Heroku Toolbelt, ImageMagick, Rbenv, Redis, Tmux, and more. Don't worry though as it'll automatically skip what you have already setup.

To install Thoughtbot's setup, execute the script below:

```
curl --remote-name https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/laptop/master/mac
less mac
sh mac 2>&1 | tee ~/laptop.log
```

For more info, visit https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop

Comment: ahh I am on Ubuntu though

Comment: Shoot, I was going to ask but was praying you had a Mac. Hopefully my answer will help similar people who have your same issue (when they Google it) find a quick solution for setting up their development environment.

Comment: I sometimes pray too, but no one hears my pray :))

Thanks anyways I had PG libraries missing and its been fixed with below answer